# Is the use of "different" weird here?: "pronounced different"

Tags: word-usage

Is the use of "different" below unnatural? There's a phrase "think different," but is using "different" as an adverb --like "differently"-- outside of that particular phrase weird?

> "Here the 'r' in 'similar' pronounced different than the general American 'r'"

Comment: I don't get it. What is your pronunciation? We can't even attempt to answer without that.

Comment: No, that's just an example sentence I made up. I don't get why I get downvotes on this. I'm not a native speaker so my English might be making my questions confusing. Is this question confusing? I didn't expect it'd be that confusing.

Comment: I upvoted your question because I understand your question. Hopefully my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in meaning between "Think different" (i.e., the adjective) and "Think differently" (the adverb), albeit a small one.

Using an adjective after a verb that is not a "be" verb may seem ungrammatical, but it is an established pattern. A clearer example is "Act nice" vs. "Act nicely."

"Act nice" means "Act as if you are nice," implying that you are not a nice person at heart, but are being urged to act as if you are. The adjective is therefore used to indicate **essence**. It urges the person to act in a way that will make people think he is (and always has been) a nice person.

On the other hand, "Act nicely" is less about urging someone to portray himself as something he essentially isn't, and more about recognizing that the person being spoken to has a choice of whether to act in a way that is nice or not and recommending that he make the right choice. The adverb is therefore used to indicate **execution**. As such, it urges the person to do act in a way that will facilitate good relations, as opposed to acting in a way that will simply garner a good opinion of him.

Using the word "think," rather than "act," blurs the adjectival/adverbial distinction somewhat, probably because thinking is not as manifest a behavior as acting; but, basically, "Think different" is urging someone to think in a way that distinguishes his thinking from conventional thinking, and that makes his thinking essentially different from that of others.

On the other hand, "Think differently" is more about urging someone to think differently from how he previously thought (although, for the reasons mentioned above, it can also be interpreted to mean much the same as "Think different.")

So, although there is a difference between using verb + adjective and verb + adverb, the magnitude of the difference depends on the choice of verb.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to Apple's successful [Think Different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different) campaign, *pronounced different* doesn't work in the way you intend except perhaps colloquially.

With *think different*, it is possible to treat the phrase as an imperative, in the sense of *do this* or *come here*. Note that the first word has to be in the present tense, not past. Treating *pronounce different* the same way simply ends up asking people to pronounce the word *different* (e.g. *diff-rent* vs *diff-e-rent* vs ...).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is really at the heart of *prescriptive* vs. *descriptive* grammar.

**Prescriptive grammar** would say that the phrase "pronounced different" is wrong because the verb requires an adverb to modify it, rather than an adjective.

**Descriptive grammar** would say that we hear this use of verb followed by adjective all the time, and people will know what you mean in general conversation. Saying that it's incorrect simply because it doesn't follow the rules doesn't change the facts.

**Both positions are true.** So as a non-native English speaker, the question for you remains: What is your goal? Are you trying to be colloquially accepted, or academically accepted?

For further reading, here's a nice brief explanation: [Understanding Prescriptive vs. Descriptive Grammar](http://amyrey.web.unc.edu/classes/ling-101-online/tutorials/understanding-prescriptive-vs-descriptive-grammar/)

By the way, if you really want to see linguists get in a good argument, ask them if 'different from' or 'different than' is correct... :)

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how weird it was. Does this particular usage of "different" as an adverb outside Apple's "think different" seem uneducated, or be indicative that the speaker is non-native? Or by "colloquial" is it just technically wrong, and people don't even blink if a native speaker use "different" this way in real life when talking to their friends or family?

Comment: It sounds non-academic and to an extent uneducated. Your last sentence is what I was getting at -- people speak this way all the time with their friends and family, but it's technically incorrect. My best advice would be to avoid using expressions that are not prescribed grammar until you're comfortable with the weirder nuances of English.